# Rate limiting on NGINX grouping by IP address

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, throttling, rate-limiting

We are trying to implement a request rate limit on our Django NGINX server. I went through some articles about how to do this, such as https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-http/.

I can see that there's the ability to put a specific rate limit on an IP address, and also on a specific "location", that is an API endpoint. But is it also possible to group together some IP addresses and apply a cumulative rate limit.

For example, we have a partner that has 5 IP addresses and we want to apply a rate limit of let's say 10 rps on a specific API (/users/), but this 10 rps is a cumulative limit on all the 5 IP addresses, and NOT 10 rps for EACH IP address. I couldn't find on the official NGINX docs or anywhere on Google if this is possible or not.

For more clarity, let's consider these examples

`123.123.123.123` - `/users` - `10 rps`

`123.123.123.123` - `/products` - `15 rps`

`45.45.45.45`, `65.65.65.65` - `/users` - `20 rps`

`45.45.45.45`, `65.65.65.65` - `/products` - `30 rps`

So API requests to `/users` endpoint from IP `123.123.123.123` should be limited to `10 rps`, and `/products` endpoint from the same IP should have a limit of `15 rps`.

API requests to `/users` endpoint from both `45.45.45.45` and `65.65.65.65` COMBINED should be limited to `20 rps`.
Similarly, for `/products` endpoint from both those IPs should be limited to `30 rps`.

Any other IP will have let's say a default rate limit of 5 rps, no matter what API endpoint is called.

Hope this clears up any confusion! Thanks!

Comment: In it unclear from your question, how other IP addresses should be limited (or not limited)? Should it be a limit of 10 rps for every other single IP? Or other IPs should not be limited at all? It is unable to answer your question without clarifying those subjects.

Comment: @IvanShatsky -  Hi Ivan, I've added some examples to the question. I hope that clarifies the question enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions are quite complicated. If, by example, requirements would be to apply a fixed 10 rps rate for the group of 5 IP addresses, and the same 10 rps rate for every other IP, you could do this with a single `limit_req` zone:

```
limit_req_zone $users_key zone=users:10m rate=10r/s;
geo $users_key {
    <ip1>    unique_customer_id;
    <ip2>    unique_customer_id;
    <ip3>    unique_customer_id;
    <ip4>    unique_customer_id;
    <ip5>    unique_customer_id;
    default  $binary_remote_addr;
}
server {
    ...
    location /users/ {
        limit_req zone=users;
        ... proxy request to the backend
    }
}
```

That `unique_customer_id` can be any string that won't be equal to any possible `$binary_remote_addr` value (which is a binary-packed string of 4 or 16 bytes length, so using something as simple as `1` will be enough; don't use a long id string to minimize the shared zone memory footprint).

However since your requirements are more complicated, including different rates for different users, we need to declare many different zones to achieve the result you want. The solution is based upon a fact that an empty zone key won't be accounted to limit requests with a single `limit_req` rule.

Here is the possible solution.

```
# zones definitions
limit_req_zone $unknown_customer zone=users_5:10m rate=5r/s;
limit_req_zone $customer_limited_group_1 zone=users_10:1m rate=10r/s;
limit_req_zone $customer_limited_group_2 zone=users_20:1m rate=20r/s;
limit_req_zone $unknown_customer zone=products_5:10m rate=5r/s;
limit_req_zone $customer_limited_group_1 zone=products_15:1m rate=15r/s;
limit_req_zone $customer_limited_group_2 zone=products_30:1m rate=30r/s;

# calculating keys
map $remote_addr $unknown_customer {
    123.123.123.123    '';
    45.45.45.45        '';
    65.65.65.65        '';
    # exclude any other IP for customers with different rates here, e.g.
    # 124.124.124.124  '';
    # 85.85.85.85      '';
    default            $binary_remote_addr;
}
map $remote_addr $customer_limited_group_1 {
    123.123.123.123    1;
    # here you can add another customers limited to 10/15 rps with another id, e.g.
    # 124.124.124.124  2;
    # the default value will be an empty string
}
map $remote_addr $customer_limited_group_2 {
    # this will be a key for a different zone;
    # value '1' does not interfere with the '1' from the previous map block in any way
    45.45.45.45        1;
    65.65.65.65        1;
    # another customers limited to 20/30 rps can be added here with different ids, e.g.
    # 85.85.85.85      2;
}

server {
    ...
    location /users/ {
        limit_req zone=users_5;
        limit_req zone=users_10;
        limit_req zone=users_20;
        ... proxy request to the backend
    }
    location /products/ {
        limit_req zone=products_5;
        limit_req zone=products_15;
        limit_req zone=products_30;
        ... proxy request to the backend
    }
}
```

Comment: In the example above, doesn't it mean that requests arriving from 123.123.123.123, 45.45.45.45, and 65.65.65.65 to /users/ will not be rate limited because the key is empty? According to [NGINX documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_zone) "Requests with an empty key value are not accounted"